# Javascript redirection and zend MVC

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, model-view-controller, redirect

Thanks for looking here. 
I'm trying to use Zend framework with MVC and I'm facing an issue regarding the link.

Here is the javascript that I'm using to redirect:

```
$("#liFoo").click(function(){
    window.location.replace('index/actionFoo);
});
```

When clicking on the link it works fine from the url: `http://domain/` I'm redirected to `http://domain/index/actionFoo`

But it doesn't work from : `http://domain/index/` (that is actually the same page than the previous one) Because I'm redirected to `http://domain/index/index/actionFoo`.

How could I solve this issue without using the full url (I don't know the domain yet...) ?
What is the best way to do it ?

Many thanks in advance,
Cedric. - begineer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use an absolute path (one with a `/` at the start):

```
$("#liFoo").click(function(){
    window.location = '/index/actionFoo';
});
```